# get count number in my SQL using php echo

Tags: php, wordpress, count

```
$countall = $wpdb->get_results
("SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count_all' FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.post_status='publish' AND wp_posts.post_type='tribe_events' OR wp_posts.post_type='post';");
```

as you can see, I am not using something like `mysql_query` or `mysql_fetch_array` the query above shows the count as normal in mysql but I want to output it.

I tried: `echo $countall->count_all;` but the result is empty, how do I get the count without changing the code above?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/ - this returns an array or object, not a single string or number. You can't echo that directly. Dump it out so you can see the structure, then write code to get the specific item you need from within it.